# C: creating index, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, string, pointers, indexing, struct

I created the next index code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct wordlist {
    char *value;
    int *lines;
    struct wordlist *next;
};

int compare (struct wordlist *one , struct wordlist *two) {
    return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}

void add(struct wordlist **pp, char *value, int line) {

    struct wordlist *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->value = value;

    for ( ; *pp != NULL; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
        if (compare(*pp, new) == 0) {
            return;
        }
        else if (compare(*pp, new) > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    new->next = *pp;
    *pp = new;
}

void display(struct wordlist *ptr) {

    for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
    }
}
```

its too much code
so i break it to submit. sorry

```
int main(void) {
    struct wordlist *root = NULL;
    int c;
    char *word;
    word = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int line = 1;
    for (int i = 0;;i++) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (!isalpha(c)) {
            i = -1;
            add(&root, word, line);
            word = malloc(sizeof(char));
            if (c == '\n') {
                line++;
            }
            continue;
        }
        c = tolower(c);
        word[i] = c;
        word = realloc(word,(i+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

It suppose to break the string by every thing which is not a a-z or A-Z char.

When I debug my code by giving him a string like

> yonatan.lif

He is printing:

> lif yonatanp

As my output should be

> lif yonatan

(I don't want the 'p' or any other char to be there)

As long as the input is the longer the length of the chars after the string that shouldn't be there

It works but it acts in the way I described with long inputs and I can't figure out why. Can you please help me figure what I'm doing wrong?

thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: So what do you see when you debug your code?

Comment: When I'm entering yonatan.lif I get
lif
yonatanp

Comment: 1) CString requires a null-terminator(`'\0'`) at the end of the string.

Comment: wow problem solved ty so much

Comment: `word = realloc(word,(i+1)*sizeof(char));` Advice: dont do this. Your code will call realloc() once*per character* . Instead: allocate too much and change  the size with larger increments. BTW: your initial allocation`sizeof (char*)` is wrong. (but harmless)

Comment: Ok I'll notice this next time, thanks

Comment: @Yonlif I see you edited your question, what's the problem now? And what have you fixed via the discussion in the comments? I am a bit lost with your code. This line `word = malloc(sizeof(char));;` does allocate space for 1 char only, is that what you want?

Comment: Ok @gsamaras I edited it again, I think its more clear now: I have code, It's not doing what I want him to do, I describe how, I'm asking for help. If you think I should edit it please say how.

Comment: Yes it should, thats only for realloc later @gsamaras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Strings in C must be null terminating*** when you are working with functions provided by most of the standard headers, such as `strcmp()`, `printf()`, and so on. From [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)'s ref:

> This function starts comparing the first character of each string.
>   [...] it continues [...] *until a terminating null-character is
>   reached*.

This is what causing the *Undefined Behavior* you are invoking, but not null terminating your strings. To do so, modify your code to:

```
word[i] = '\0';
i = -1;
add(&root, word, line);
```

Now your words will be null terminated and your program shall function properly.

---

Here is the scenario of what is happening to your program (*You* should take a piece of paper and a pencil and draw what your code does next time).

1. `word` points to "yonatan".
2. You meat '.', thus `add()` is called.
3. There a `new` struct is created, where it's `next` member will be
   set to `root`, which is `NULL`, `value` to where `word` points to,
   and `line`...well this member will remain uninitialized (it should
   be probably be set to 0, but you know better).
4. We continue and now `word` forgets about "yonatan" and points to
   "lif".
5. `add()` is called again, where another `new` struct is created, with
   its `value` to "lif" and its `next` to the previously-created
   struct, at step 3. That's why your words will be printed in reserve
   from their input order. `line` will be left uninitialized again.
6. `display()` is called, but the `%s` format seeks for the null
   terminator to stop, which your strings might lack, thus invoking
   undefined behavior (the junk characters you are witnessing, like
   'p').

Now you should ask and what about my for loop and `compare()` functions? You will enter that loop once `add()` is called for the 2nd time, and your `compare()` function is called, but without null terminated strings `strcmp()` fails to do its job properly, and my guess is that it returns a junk positive value, which breaks the loop.

---

PS: Not a problem, but may cause confusion to reader:

```
char *word;
word = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

Why you allocate space for a pointer? You probably meant to just to this:

```
word = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Thanks. "*You should take a piece of paper and a pencil and draw what your code does next time*" defiantly gonna use it.